# Are Windows partitions gone?

Tags: 11.04, windows-7, laptop, vaio, command-line

I had Windows 7 on my laptop (factory setting), because of some performance issues, I decided to use recovery options to restore it to its factory condition but I don't know what has happened or what I have done that the whole operating system was gone after playing around with recovery options from the boot menu. I couldn't find Windows, so I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop. Last time I had Ubuntu on it, it was not really compatible with laptop's configuration and I had a bit of problems trying to do normal tasks I used to do on Windows. Now I want to make sure that Windows and its drivers are gone so that I can try to install a newer version of Ubuntu or Windows. I tried the command

```
 sudo fdisk -l
```

And the result shown was:

```
 myaccount@myaccount-VPCS116FG:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for myaccount:

 Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00025b5f

 Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 1 38409 308515840 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 38409 38914 4052993 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 38409 38914 4052992 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/dm-0: 4150 MB, 4150263808 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 504 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa668cfe8

Disk /dev/dm-0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Is it gone? If not, what command should I try to have access to Windows partitions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Windows is gone.  Good job!  :-)

You should try Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which will be supported until April 2017, or perhaps the 12.10 latest release if 12.04 is still lacking hardware support specific to your machine.

If you have problems you should search for solutions here, and ask a question if you have trouble finding the answer.